# Is there a way to know the total time computer was unlocked per day?

Tags: windows-10, time, lock-screen

In other words, I unlocked my PC for 3 hours today, Locked it for 1 hour and then unlocked it for another 3 hours.
what can tell me that the computer was active for only 6 hours today?

Comment: If using Windows, you can pull the values from Event Viewer _(I don't believe Group Policy Audit rules have to be enabled, but I could be wrong)_.  As to what logs in Event Viewer to review, I'm not sure.  If using Linux, see [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux+login+log&atb=v185-4&ia=web)

Comment: Windows computers (and I am sure other operating systems) can continue working while locked (downloading files or updates for example). I do not think there is a useful measure of locking a computer.

Answer (score 1):

If using windows, you can use the event log, provided you have the correct options* enabled. Then you can programmatically compare or by hand.

The event codes are: 4648 (Logon), 4647 (LogOff), 4624 (Logon), 4800 (Workstation lock)

An free tool that computes the time for the unlocked period is here: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/windows_log_on_times_view.html

- Options include "Audit Other Login/Logoff Events" audit policy configuration of Windows.